# INSERT SELECT FROM VALUES casting

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-types

It's often desirable to INSERT from a SELECT expression (e.g. to qualify with a WHERE clause), but this can get postgresql confused about the column types.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE example (a uuid primary key, b numeric);
INSERT INTO example 
SELECT a, b 
FROM (VALUES ('d853b5a8-d453-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a', NULL)) as data(a,b);
=> ERROR:  column "a" is of type uuid but expression is of type text
```

This can be fixed by explicitly casting in the values:

```
INSERT INTO example 
SELECT a, b 
FROM (VALUES ('d853b5a8-d453-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a'::uuid, NULL::numeric)) as data(a,b);
```

But that's messy and a maintenance burden. Is there some way to make postgres understand that the VALUES expression has the same type as a table row, i.e. something like

```
VALUES('d853b5a8-d453-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a', NULL)::example%ROWTYPE
```

Edit:

The suggestion of using (data::example).* is neat, but unfortunately it complete seems to screw up the postgres query planner when combined with a WHERE clause like so:

```
INSERT INTO example 
SELECT (data::example).* 
FROM (VALUES ('d853b5a8-d453-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a', NULL)) as data 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM example 
                  WHERE (data::example) 
                  IS NOT DISTINCT FROM example);
```

This takes minutes with a large table.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "screw up the planer" I assume you mean "bad performance". That condition will of course not use _any_ index on that table. If you want the `where` condition to make use of an index, you need to compare indexed columns, not the whole record

Comment: Why "of course"? It seems hardly declarative that  adding the (as far as I can see) redundant conjunction `WHERE (data::example).a = a  AND (data::example) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM example ` results in dramatically different performance behavior.

Comment: Because you can't create an index that contains the complete record. An index can only contain columns  - and even all columns in an index wouldn't be the same as an index with the complete record

Comment: Why would an index on the complete record be needed? The two records match If and only if all the columns match. Why on earth wouldn't postgres use the primary key on `a` to look up `data.a` in `example` and then compare the matching row, if any, with `data::example`? No other row could possibly match, so the linear scan baffles me.

Comment: Because you compare complete records with the expression `(data::example) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM example` - you are not comparing a single (primary key) column. Plus: the expression `(data::example)` contains no information about primary keys because a an object _type_ does not have a primary key. Only a table has a primary key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* cast a record to a row type of your table:

```
INSERT INTO example 
SELECT (data::example).*
FROM (
    VALUES 
      ('d853b5a8-d453-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a', NULL),
      ('54514c89-f188-490a-abbb-268f9154ab2c', 42)
) as data;
```

`data::example` casts the complete row to a record of type `example`. The `(...).*` then turns that into the columns defined in the table type `example`

Comment: Nice feature :) But I guess it depends on column order in subquery which could cause problems when you have multiple environments and scripts are applied in different order. For example envA: example(col1, col2, col3) and envB: example(col1, col3, col2).

Comment: That's quite concise! But unfortunately it also seems to come with some serious performance problems when combined with a WHERE query, I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @as.: please don't extend your question to a broader scope once you get an answer on the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `VALUES` directly:

```
INSERT INTO example(a, b)
VALUES ('d853b5a8-d453-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a', NULL);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=5727256fa270e043e64b3c1ff00c1141)**

---

Or just cast once:

```
INSERT INTO example(a, b)
SELECT a::uuid, b::numeric
FROM (VALUES ('d853b5a8-d453-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a', NULL), 
             ('bb53b5a8-d453-11e7-9296-cec278b6b50a',1) ) as data(a,b);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c27ca01d43a3fa503fe2d3b96cc2e22a)**

Note, please always explicitly define columns list.